# Discrete infinite graphs, harmonic functions and recurrence:

Tags: probability-theory, recurrence-relations, martingales

I'm looking at $\mathbb N_0$ as a directed graph:

for every vertex $n$ there are 2 edges:

one goes to $n+1$ with probability $0<p_n<1$
and one goes to $n-1$ with probability $1-p_n$

[from 0 there is only one edge going to 1 with prob 1]

Let's say I have a function $h:\mathbb N_0\rightarrow \mathbb R$ which is harmonic on $\mathbb N$ [without 0]. I have proven it exists and unique.

[discrete harmonic on weighted graph: $h(j)= \sum_{n\in S} P(n,j)h(j)$ where $S$ is the set of vertices that has an edge directed to $j$

Now I'm asked to prove that the graph is recurrent iff $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}h(n)=\infty$.

I have no clue how to do it.
I think it's related to martingales and doob's optional stopping time theorem, but I have no clue.

Comment: What does it mean for a function to be harmonic on the positive integers?

Comment: @GerryMyerson thanks, updated the question with definition.

Comment: Thanks. $P(n,j)$ is an arbitrary function of two variables?

Comment: @GerryMyerson nope, $P(n,j)$ is the probability to move from vertex $n$ to vertex $j$